# Multiplied subscription

Tags: angular, observable, subscription

In one component I have two subscriptions, one for query parameters, one for http GET request.
On this page user also has an option to switch between different types of data (only one type can be displayed). When user clicks one option, query parameter is updated and the subscription is updated, so the http GET request is called again and the data is also updated, as below:

```
constructor(private service: DataService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            this.dataType = params["dataType"];
                this.service
                    .getData(this.dataType)
                    .subscribe(data => {
                        this.data=data;
                    })
        })
}
```

In html:

```
  [queryParams]="{ dataType: row.dataType}"
```

The problem is, that every time user clicks different type of data, new subscription is created from the http GET request, because everything is happening within the same component. So, when component is created: 2 subscriptions,
user clicks new data type: new data loaded and 3 subscriptions, user click different data type, new data loaded and 4 subscriptions and so on. As you can imagine after 4-5 clicks the page just crashes.

I've been trying to find a solution for this problem (specifically loading data in the same component based on users choice), but I cant figure out how to do that.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: where is the code that you reload data when user clicks new data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will not solve your issue, but you're using two asynchronous event one in the other. This is not a good practise.

You can update your code with that :

```js
this.route.queryParams.pipe(
    switchMap(params => this.service.getData(params["dataType"]))
).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
```

To solve your subscription issue, did you try to add a `ngOnDestroy()` function ?

Comment: yes but ngOnDestroy() is never called in this case because the component is not being destroyed, changes in data happen within the component. But the code that you wrote above seems to be working, I've tested it and it seems like it doesnt multiply subscriptions anymore, so big thanks !

Answer (score 2):

A bit of RxJS pipeable operators should solve this:

`switchMap` - will cancel previous http request and switch to latest
use `takeUntil` method for unsubscribing
`tap` for side effect (a little ugly not doing this within subscribe)

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.pipe(
    map(params => params["dataType"]),
    tap(dataType => {
      this.dataType = dataType
    }),
    switchMap(dataType => this.service.getData(this.dataType)),
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
  ).subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
  })
}
```

**Edit** - make takeUntil the last operator!

Answer (score 2):

Http methods are cold observables, so you do not need to unsubscribe. It will be unsubscribed automatically.

Instead you should unsubscribe `router.queryParams` subscription which is a hot observable. This subscription is getting created multiple times in your code.

This can be done within `ngOnDestroy` life cycle hook

```
routerSub: Subscription;

constructor(private service: DataService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
        this.routerSub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            this.dataType = params["dataType"];
                this.service
                    .getData(this.dataType)
                    .subscribe(data => {
                        this.data=data;
                    })
        })
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.routerSub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

save your current subscription in a variable and then close it before you create a new one:

```js
subscription: currSubscribtion;

constructor(private service: DataService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    if (currSubscribtion) {
      this.currSubscribtion.unsubscribe()
    }
    
    this.dataType = params["dataType"];
    this.currSubscribtion = this.service.getData(this.dataType)
      .subscribe(data => {
          this.data=data;
      })
  })
}
```